# picker view for row not calling some time

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uipickerview

I added my picker view to my main view programatically. If I touch on picker view, it touches the test scroll not the pickerview, so I am not able select a row from pickerview.

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    viewForValueForPicker = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(125, txtvisitReason.frame.origin.y+txtvisitReason.frame.size.height, 180, 160)];
    UIToolbar *toolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(125, 0, 180, 30)];
    toolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
    UIBarButtonItem *btn = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(doneBtnPressToGetValue)]autorelease];
    [toolBar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:btn]];
    [viewForValueForPicker addSubview:toolBar];

    pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(125, 30, 180, 140)];
    pickerView.delegate=self;
    pickerView.dataSource=self;
    pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator=YES;
    [viewForValueForPicker addSubview:pickerView];
    [testscroll addSubview:viewForValueForPicker];// test scroll is my scroll view object i added scroll view to main view 
    [txtvisitReason resignFirstResponder];
```

}

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch{
   if(touch.view==testscroll){
        viewForValueForPicker.hidden=YES;
        return YES; //If its the main view accept the touch
   }    else
   return NO; //Otherwise(say tableview) don't consume the touch.
```

}

I implemented tapgesture delegate method here it is showing main view even when I touch the picker view.if touch on picker view touch.view is showing test scroll and my picker disappears.

Comment: I am really confused by this question. Can you clarify it?

Comment: the view for row method is not getting called

Comment: you can set [testscroll setDelaysContentTouches:YES]; property for your scrollview ,it may solve your problem

Comment: @DipenPanchasara its not working i think my picker view is in begin editing method not in view did load this is te main issue